# Weird issue with Firefox toolbar

Tags: linux-mint, firefox, cinnamon

Since Firefox 57 (I'm currently on 69) I've been having a weird issue with its toolbar. When I open the browser, sometimes it looks like that:

[image: Weird Firefox toolbar with no add-ons on startup]

Every time that happens, I have to go to the ">>" button on the far right, then "Customize toolbar..." - by the time I do that, the toolbar backs to normal. Like this:

[Showing the Firefox toolbar issue (YouTube)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0ZkIl2DhtHE)

I want to solve this bug somehow, as it's really annoying when I have to do this workaround sometimes. I want my entire toolbar, with all my add-ons, as it's always supposed to be, all the time. Is there some fix for that?

OS: Linux Mint 19.2 "Tina" amd64
DE: Cinnamon 4.2.4

Comment: The 'Restore Defaults' option under the 'Customize' page may be helpful. Can you give it a try?

Comment: Just tried it right now, let's see if that issue comes back or not.

Comment: Did the "restore defaults" procedure a while ago an restarted Firefox about 35 times already. The issue hasn't happened so far, so it may be something with the extension buttons, or the search box on the right. I'll keep testing here.

Comment: Now added the AdBlock Plus extension button to see what happens - toolbar behaving normally, so now I think it's something with one of the other extensions I generally use.

Comment: Now I think I found the actual problem: I had too many extensions on my toolbar. I selected just a few of them now (AdBlock Plus and MEGA) and, since then, the bug stopped, and the toolbar is normal again. I can consider this solved.

Comment: That's good news. Consider adding that as an answer, so you can mark this question as closed. From my side, I'm not sure if 'too many extensions' is a problem for Firefox. I'm inclined to think that the config file which stores toolbar preferences may have been corrupted at some point.

Answer (score 0):

By doing some more research, I finally found the **actual** solution: to disable the search box on the right. Go to the three-line menu, then "Customize..." and drag out the search box, then close the tab. That toolbar issue will never happen again.